# Angular Material Design 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

I've this table, build using [this](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) material design component:
[image]

Like you see, I'm using the slide toggle from [material design](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/overview).

My goal is that I can't have more than one selected per row. I want to select one, and disable the other ones from the correspondent row.

I can't find a kind of group for slide toggle. [API](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api) seems not to help to much on this.

Can anyone give me a help?

This is how the table is build:

```
     Administrator Column 
    <ng-container mdColumnDef="administrator">
        <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> Administrateur </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *mdCellDef="let user">
            <md-slide-toggle 
                id="admin_{{user.id}}"
                [checked]="checkRole('ROLE_ADMIN', user)" 
                name="ROLE_ADMIN"
                (change)="setRoles($event, user)">
            </md-slide-toggle>
        </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

     Advanced User Column 
    <ng-container mdColumnDef="advancedUser">
        <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> Utilisateur avancé </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *mdCellDef="let user">
            <md-slide-toggle 
                id="advanced_user_{{user.id}}"
                [checked]="checkRole('ROLE_ADVANCED', user)" 
                name="ROLE_ADVANCED"
                (change)="setRoles($event, user)">
            </md-slide-toggle>
        </md-cell>
    </ng-container>

     Collaborator Column 
    <ng-container mdColumnDef="collaborator">
        <md-header-cell *mdHeaderCellDef> Collaborateur </md-header-cell>
        <md-cell *mdCellDef="let user">
            <md-slide-toggle 
                id="user_{{user.id}}"
                [checked]="checkRole('ROLE_USER', user)" 
                name="ROLE_USER"
                (change)="setRoles($event, user)">
            </md-slide-toggle>
        </md-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

Thank you all!!

Best regards,
Marcelo

Comment: It's against the material guidelines to use groups for slide toggles button, that's why it is not supported, you should use radio buttons instead. User will get confused if you keep slide toggles.

Comment: Thanks Ploppy :)